# Windows 8 Smart Screen

Tags: c#, certificate, windows-8.1

I have some weird behavior of smart screen on Windows 8.

I have set up ASP.NET server on my computer, and I have a hello world application signed with certificate I bought.

When I start this singed application it shows me Smart Screen which is expected. If my friend downloads this file using URL I gave it to him, and he downloads it with Firefox (Both computers are connected in LAN) and then start application it shows him Smart Screen which is expected too. However if he tries to download it using C# application he wrote with `WebClient.DownloadFile()` or `WebClient.DownloadData()` methods and then starts it manually it does not show Smart Screen on his computer which is odd, same things happens if I try do download it using his application on my computer. But If he then sends me that downloaded application via Skype and I return to him that same file via Skype, then he has 2 copies of completely identical application where the one I returned to him via Skype shows smart screen but one that he downloaded via C# application does not.

So we tried second approach in which I send him application via Sockets (using SCS Framework), same thing happens. It does not show smart screen on his computer but on my it does. If he sends me that application that he received via Socket, and I start it, it shows me smart screen but when I return that application via Skype then it shows him smart screen too, when he runs it.

Also if he signed my application on his computer with my certificate, there is no smart screen on his computer when he starts it. But there is on mine computer when he sends it to me, and when I returned that application he signed on his computer, via Skype, then there is Smart Screen on his computer when he runs it.

In whole this process Run Anyway button that is shown by smart screen is never clicked and always same application and same certificate is used.

Few days ago there was also problem few applications signed with my certificates were showing smart screen on few computers, but on few computers there wasn't smart screen at all.

I am not sure I've explained my problem here well, but all I know is that when I run this application on several computers sometimes there is Smart Screen, and sometimes there isn't.

Why is this happening and is there any workaround? I really need to know will Smart Screen be shown on other computers. What I read somewhere is that every certificate builds its reputation after which Smart Screen stops to pop up. I need to catch this moment. So I figured I should run my application 2-3 times a day to see if Smart Screen is still popping out, but my approach is not reliable that much as this test confirms it, or am I doing something wrong. Both machines are running Windows 8.1 x64 and SignTool.exe from Windows SDK to sign files. Certificate extension is p12. Is there any other way to test same thing that Smart Screen filter is testing/looking for?

Comment: Alternate Data Streams. Browsers write an alternate stream indicating that the file was downloaded from the internet. WebClient doesn't do this. But instead of writing a couple paragraphs, perhaps create a table of when SmartScreen shows up on which computer and when it doesn't, because your story is quite hard to follow. What exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is how can I make smart screen showing always, and is there any other way i check will smart screen pop up or not. You may help me with this Alternate Data Streams as I will check it tomorrow, but that does not explain how can same application signed on my friends computer not showing smart screen, but when the same application is singed / transferred  to my computer it does show smart screen.